# Where does libhdf5.so get stored after running `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`?

Tags: apt, software-installation

New user to Ubuntu (running 16.04) here. I need to use HDF5, more specifically: I need `ld -lhdf5` be able to run without error.

As far as I can tell, what should work is running `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`. This generates the folder at `/usr/include/hdf5/` as expected. However when I run:
`ld -lhdf5`
I get:
`ld: cannot find -lhdf5`
When I run:
`ld -lhdf5 --verbose`
I get as last few lines:

```
==================================================
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libhdf5.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libhdf5.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libhdf5.a failed
ld: cannot find -lhdf5
```

None of these places contain ideed this file or something similar. Can anyone help me where it should be?

Comment: You might have to run 'sudo apt-get install libhdf5' to install the library itself. The -dev package is, to my knowlegde, only the header-files.

Comment: It's going to depend on your Ubuntu **version** I think: newer versions use an explicit `serial` subdirectory IIRC. Regardless you can do `dpkg -L libhdf5-dev`. Or see the file list at [File list of package libhdf5-dev in xenial of architecture amd64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libhdf5-dev/filelist)

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install libhdf5`, I get `E: Unable to locate package libhdf5`. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Ah thanks, it was in: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/`. If you add the part about `dpkg -L libhdf5-dev` as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The location of the particular library lies in running

```
dpkg -L libhdf5-dev
```

which for my installation lies in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so
```