# libhdf5 installation problem

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc, ld

I've installed `libhdf5-dev` with apt-get but `gcc` cannot find it:

```
~$ locate libhdf5.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so
~$ gcc -lhdf5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/870237/where-does-libhdf5-so-get-stored-after-running-sudo-apt-get-install-libhdf5-dev/1003834#1003834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help `ld` to find your `hdf5` library you can add the following flag:

```
-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

i.e.

```
~$ gcc -lhdf5 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

> [man gcc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gcc.1.html)
>
> ```
> -Ldir
>    Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.
> ```

---

[Official install instructions](https://github.com/tiangolo/caffe/blob/e12f3e4c565f68111bdbab396f7b256ac57de4f5/docs/install_apt2.md)

**Configure the HDF5 version**

Note: this is a quick fix for a minor bug / issue with the version of libhdf5. If you know a better / proper way to solve it, let me know. If this section doesn't apply to you, omit it.

1. Go to the libraries directory:

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
   ```
2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for libraries in Anacoda, such as libhdf5.so.10, libhdf5_hl.so.10:

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Update the "Dynamic Linker":

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

Comment: Obviously I'm not using ld or gcc directly but a more complex build system

Comment: Adding this path to the build library dir worked. But why doesn't ubuntu install this package in the correct location?

Comment: seems like a [known issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1463). I've added to my answer the official install instructions

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it by adding the search path to my build system config, which is a bit cleaner solution.